# Running scrapy tasks in a loop

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have this code:

```
    from logging import INFO

    import scrapy

    class LinkedInAnonymousSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "linkedin_anonymous"
        allowed_domains = ["linkedin.com"]
        start_urls = []

        base_url = "https://www.linkedin.com/pub/dir/?first=%s&last=%s&search=Search"

        def __init__(self, input=None, first=None, last=None):
            self.input = input  # source file name
            self.first = first
            self.last = last

        def start_requests(self):
            if self.first and self.last: # taking input from command line parameters
                url = self.base_url % (self.first, self.last)
                yield self.make_requests_from_url(url)
            elif self.input: # taking input from file
                i = 0
                self.log('Input from file: %s' % self.input, INFO)
                for line in open(self.input, 'r').readlines():
                    i += 1
                    if line.strip(): # no blank line
                        t = line.split("\t")
                        name = t[0]
                        parts = [n.strip() for n in name.split(' ')]
                        last = parts.pop()
                        first = " ".join(parts)

                        if first and last:
                            url = self.base_url % (first, last)
                            yield self.make_requests_from_url(url)
            else:
                raise Exception('No input.')

        def parse(self, response):
            # if there is exactly one match the person's profile page is returned
            if response.xpath('//div[@class="profile-overview-content"]').extract():
                yield scrapy.Request(response.url, callback=self.parse_full_profile_page)
            else:
                # extracting profile urls from search result
                for sel in response.css('div.profile-card'):
                    url = sel.xpath('./*/h3/a/@href').extract()[0]  # Person's full profile URL in LinkedIn
                    yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_full_profile_page)
........
```

With this code, I get the profile details of a list of people from linkedin.

I have written such a main function in order to do that.

```
import scrapy
import sys

from linkedin_anonymous_spider import LinkedInAnonymousSpider
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from twisted.internet import reactor

if __name__ == "__main__":
        firstname = ['Hasan', 'James']
        lastname = ['Arslan', 'Bond']
        for a in range(len(firstname)):
                settings = get_project_settings()
                crawler = CrawlerProcess(settings)
                spider = LinkedInAnonymousSpider()
                crawler.crawl(spider, [], firstname[a], lastname[a])
                crawler.start()
```

When the loop comes to the 2nd step, I get this error:

> raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()
>   twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable

How can I fix the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only run one reactor, so just calling `crawler.start()` once.

Try passing `crawler.start()` out of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a correct version:

```
firstname = ['Hasan', 'James']
lastname = ['Arslan', 'Bond']
settings = get_project_settings()
crawler = CrawlerProcess(settings)

for a in range(len(firstname)):
    crawler.crawl(LinkedInAnonymousSpider, [], firstname[a], lastname[a])

crawler.start()
```